# Python con SQL y excel

Tags: python, sql, excel

Quería saber si hay alguna forma de que si puedo usar una base datos con SQL en python y  luego, la base de datos me lo pase a planillas de excel en el mismo python

Comment: Pandas es una buena opción. Otra es escribir un código que tome los datos de la base de datos y cree un excel usando openpyxl

Comment: En cuanto al excel, tienes [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) y [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/). Este ultimo es generalmente bastante mas eficiente, aunque también algo menos flexible en algunos aspectos. Ademas de algunas otras librerías que dependiendo de tu caso pueden serte de ayuda (como Pandas que menciona Dante) y que por lo general usan openpyxl o XlsxWriter por debajo como backend. En cuanto a SQL dependiendo de la base de datos que uses MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, etc, tendrás que instalar un conector u otro. Python en su stlib solo soporta SQLite.